# Can not output salary and mobile number. It's always produced an unexpected result in C

Tags: c, string, structure

In my C program, I expected the result of salary and mobile number that I entered But it's produced some unexpected result. Why it's happened? Please help me any one to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 struct employee
{
   int emp_id;
   char name[20];
   char address[50];
   int salary[11];
   int mobile[11];
};
void main()
{
   struct employee e1, e2;

   //Get value for employee 1

   printf("Enter the id of employee 1: \n");
   scanf("%d", &e1.emp_id);
   printf("Enter the name of employee 1: \n");
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(e1.name);
   printf("Enter the address of employee 1: \n");
   gets(e1.address);
   printf("Enter the salary of employee 1: \n");
   scanf("%d", &e1.salary);
   printf("Enter the mobile number of employee 1: \n");
   scanf("%d", &e1.mobile);

   //Output the value

   printf("Value of employee 1\n\n");
   printf("Id: %d\n", e1.emp_id); //Output right
   printf("Name: %s\n", e1.name); //Output right
   printf("Address: %s\n", e1.address); //Output right
   printf("Salary: %d\n", e1.salary); // Unexpected result
   printf("Mobile: %d\n", e1.mobile); // Unexpected result

  }
```

Comment: `int salary[11];  int mobile[11];` --> ``int salary;  int mobile;``

Comment: NEVER use `gets()`.   It is fraught with problems, most notably there is nothing to stop the user from overrunning the input buffer, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest using `fgets()`  Also, the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for some time and is completely removed from the latest C standard.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `fflush()` is ONLY for output streams, so applying it to an input stream (stdin) is undefined behavior.   (Note: some compiler manufactures have implemented it for `stdin` but that is not standard and should not be used.

Comment: this line: `gets(e1.name);` would be much better written as: `fgets( e1.name, sizeof(e1.name), stdin);`

Comment: to flush stdin, use: ` int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: this line: `int salary[11];` is defining an array of 11 integers, what you actually want is a single integer I.E. `int salary;`  Similar considerations exist for the `mobile` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`salary` and `mobile` members of the struct are *arrays*, not just one `int`. So, you can't `scanf()` it or printf() it using `%d`.

You just need to change your struct to:

```
struct employee
{
   int emp_id;
   char name[20];
   char address[50];
   int salary;
   int mobile;
};
```

Also,

- `void main()` is not a standard complaint signature for main(). Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char**argv)` or equivalent.
- `gets()` should never be used in C (which has been removed from C11 anyway). Use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) instead.

In general, pay attention to your compiler warnings as you should be getting quite a few for your code (If not, increase the warning level on your compiler toolchain).

Answer (score -1):

The first answer is correct, but you may for reasons we don't know you may want to retain all 11 elements of the salary and mobile arrays.

To do so, change your code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct employee
{
   int emp_id;
   char name[20];
   char address[50];
   int salary[11];
   int mobile[11];
};
void main()
{
   struct employee e1, e2;

   //Get value for employee 1

   printf("Enter the id of employee 1: \n");
   scanf("%d\n", &e1.emp_id);
   printf("Enter the name of employee 1: \n");
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(e1.name);
   printf("Enter the address of employee 1: \n");
   gets(e1.address);
   printf("Enter the salary of employee 1: \n");
   scanf("%d\n", &e1.salary[0]);
   printf("Enter the mobile number of employee 1: \n");
   scanf("%d\n", &e1.mobile[0]);

   //Output the value

   printf("Value of employee 1\n\n");
   printf("Id: %d\n", e1.emp_id); //Output right
   printf("Name: %s\n", e1.name); //Output right
   printf("Address: %s\n", e1.address); //Output right
   printf("Salary: %d\n", e1.salary); // Unexpected result
   printf("Mobile: %d\n", e1.mobile); // Unexpected result

  }
```

Also note that for your scanf calls you should include the newline as I've done in the above code.  This tells scanf to end its job when it encounters the newline.  Maybe not necessary, but good practice.

In addition I will disagree with the other answer about your "main signature", if you aren't inputting any command line parameters nor returning anything from main back to the system then the way you've done it is perfectly acceptable.  Actually, the way you've wrote this code would be correct practice for embedded systems code, or code running without an OS (yes, alot of code runs on it's own without an OS - but unless you do that kind of work you wouldn't know that.  And to those who say that something should "never" be done in C I say that's the programmer's prerogative. C programming is all about the programmer knowing what they are doing and why much better than any "conventional advice" which doesn't take your specific situation into account.  I use gets all the time, done it for over a third of a century - not a single issue has occurred in my code because of it.  C is not a language for academics, it's a language for hard core programmers who know what they are doing better than anyone else.  C code is inherently dangerous all by itself, at least as dangerous as using gets.  Putting training wheels on a 1000cc motorcycle doesn't do very much to make it less dangerous - the danger is in riding the motorcycle in the first place.  See what I mean?

Comment: this answer did not correct the printing of the salary and mobile fields.  the function: `gets()` doesn't even exist in the latest C standards.  Even compliant C compilers for 'bare bones' programming will output a warning if the returned type from `main()` is not `int`

Comment: Please tell me how this did not correct the printing.  As far as gets() goes, it might be depreciated but it still works just fine, regardless of what the standard says.  I don't take coding as an academic exercise, I do what works and this has served me well developing code in C for almost 40 years.  If you want an "academically correct" answer then I apologize, I'm not the person you want advice from then - I'm a pragmatist and care very little about "academic" issues.

Comment: Most likely, you have been very lucky to not be 'burned' by the `gets()` function.  Strongly suggest using the function that replaced `gets()`.  Namely the `fgets()` function.  Note: be sure to read the man page for `fgets()` as the parameters and final results are somewhat different.

Comment: One 'academic' (cough cough) issue is that the function: `gets()` will allow the user to overrun the input buffer, which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Any modern C compiler will output warnings messages about `gets()` and if using the C11 standard or later, will output an error message and not compile the code

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value, not the parameter value(s), to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: 11 bytes is barely long enough for a (no formatting) U.S. cell number.  Add a leading 1 or leading 0 or leading 00 or a country code and the buffer will overflow. And lots of people will try to enter something like (206) 123-4567 for the cell number and the posted code will fail, without the program even knowing a failure occurred.  Similar problems will occur if the user enters a `$` sign as part of the salary.

Comment: the `fflush()` function is made for output streams.  For most compilers trying to fflush() an input stream (like stdin) is undefined behavior.

Comment: embedded systems have a `start` function or `startup` function that handles several initializations before calling `main()` and still expects `main()` to return an `int`.  While `Visual Studio` will allow such invalid signatures for `main()` it is not portable and can cause numerous problems, especially if using any kind of OS.

Comment: Never been burned by gets(), and it's not luck.  I've honestly never had an overrun bug in almost 40 years of professional C coding - all it takes is being very thorough and having great attention to detail.  gets() is only dangerous if you don't bother completely checking what your code does.  As for myself, I single step through every single line of my code while checking all of my variables and buffers.  It's what we learned to do in the "old days" - never rely on anything except your own ability to know what every line of your code does, even checking it at the assembly level if needed.

Comment: the function: `gets()` will take in characters from the user until the user enters a EOF or a newline.  No code that uses `gets()` can stop a user from overrunning the input buffer.  Note: NEVER trust the user to do the right thing.   For example, on the posted code, the user can easily overrun the input buffer(s)  That is why the code should be using `fgets()` so such undefined behavior cannot happen.